# Activity Results API returned data is null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying out the new Activity Results API by trying to return a parcelable dataesque class from a child activity. Using Alpha4 of the library.

I have setup the Intent with a custom contract 'AddAttendeeContract' as per my understanding of the docs. It compiles and runs and as far as I can see the correct methods are being called but the data is just null.

What might I be missing?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ... //boilerplate setup nonsense
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            addAttendee()
        }
    }

    private val addAttendee = registerForActivityResult(AddAttendeeContract()) { attendee: AttendeeData? ->
        println("Attendee") // this does not print out
        println(attendee)   // this does not either
    }
}
```

And the contract

```
class AddAttendeeContract : ActivityResultContract<Void?, AttendeeData?>() {
    override fun createIntent(
        context: Context,
        input: Void?
    ): Intent =
        Intent(context, AddAttendeeActivity::class.java)

    override fun parseResult(
        resultCode: Int,
        intent: Intent?
    ): AttendeeData? = when {
        resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK -> null
        else -> intent?.getParcelableExtra<AttendeeData>("attendee")
    }
}
```

Finally is the invocation in the child activity class.

```
class AddAttendeeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ... //boilerplate

        add.setOnClickListener { //button on a form
            val name: String = view.name.text.toString().trim()
            val rate: Double = view.rate.text.toString().trim().toDouble()
            val number: Int = view.number.text.toString().trim().toInt()

            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("attendee", AttendeeData(name=name, rate=rate, number=number))
            }

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved. The problem was that the second activity was startign a new intent, rather than finishing and returning to the old one.

In the second/child activity had to change the line:

`startActivity(intent)`
to
`finish()` and things all worked as expected.